# Azure Scheduled VM

Tags: azure, cloud

This is essentially a question about saving money - we have build machines in azure - but they are only active for about 8 hours a day.  Is  there any easy way to create a schedule, so they are taken off line for the rest of the time, so we only pay for 1/3 the amount of compute time?

Answer (score 1):

Darren

Yes , its possible. There are two options available

1. Via Powershell 
   http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Start-Windows-Azure-b6c179b6
2. Using Azure VM As scheduler.
   http://clemmblog.azurewebsites.net/start-stop-windows-azure-vms-according-time-schedule/

Comment: Nothing off the shelf though - there isn't a VM property you can set to shut down / start up VMs. Powershell is the easiest way to achieve this.  Just dump it into Windows Scheduled Task.  Note that if you have multiple VMs that have a start order required then you need to take that into account when writing your "start" script.

Comment: Not good to post link-only answers (those links can rot, rendering your answer meaningless). How about editing your answer to give a deeper explanation or example? Plus, there are not only two options available, yet your answer alludes to those being the only choices.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that you can do is using a Powershell script to start/stop the VMs at certain times.

You can find a draft at the Azure Management Portal, under Automation ==> Runbooks.
There you can also find runbooks to scale your machines over the night, to cut costs ever more.

I hope this helps :)